# How to properly encode this local file Uri with utf8 characters

Tags: file, libcurl, utf-8

I'm trying to have libcurl download a local file with this name:

C:\Users\Lucas Meijer\Desktop\我能吞下玻璃而不傷.chinesefile

But can't seem to be able to find the proper url encoded string that will make libcurl find this.

Comment: If you are having problems, I would assume that most web users would also be having problems accessing that file. Why not just change the filename?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you should access such files using wide-strings, where each character is excatly 2 bytes long, and unicode versions of WinAPI functions should be used for accessing files. In utf-8 characters consume variable number of bytes.

I failed to solve that task from php in due time.

If you're using plain libcurl API try look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2005-02/0194.html) or google for "libcurl unicode filename".